# JSF not rendered through web.xml <welcome-file> only

Tags: jsf, tomcat, primefaces

Using JSF 2.2 with Tomcat 7.0, trying to run my project on the server using web.xml, but my JSF is never rendered. When running my index.xhtml file through run as on tomcat, the jsf is displayed without any problems at all. Here is my web.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<display-name>ProcessOrderNewGreg</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF
Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>ProcessOrderNewGreg/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>ProcessOrderNewGreg/index.xhtml/index.jsf</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>ProcessOrderNewGreg/index.xhtml/index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>ProcessOrderNewGreg/index.xhtml/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My url when running index.xhtml through run as:

```
http://localhost:8080/ProcessOrderNewGreg/index.xhtml
```

Comment: The pages that are not rendering, do they have .jsf as a suffix? For example, `http://localhost:8080/ProcessOrderNewGreg/example.jsf`?

Comment: Nope, they are all .xhtml. But I was able to get my components working. Thanks for helping though!

Comment: If you ever use faces-redirect you MIGHT run into trouble, since they get .jsf appended... anyway, good luck!

Comment: @BalusC shoot I don't know how I missed the url mapping. I'm sorry

Comment: @rion18 what do you suggest I do editing wise to avoid the possible trouble?

Comment: @Balusc was right, you already have a url mapping set, I simply didn't see it...

Comment: @rion18 so my answer looks good? 
Thanks for the help by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting my web.xml file to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<display-name>ProcessOrderNewGreg</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I was able to render all of my JSF components.